# Tortoise SVN Multiple repository question

Tags: tortoisesvn

I use Tortoise SVN and I have one repository called "First". My SVN Location is C:\SVN.

Now, I created a new project in repository "Two".

The current structure is
C:\SVN
-> First
-> Second

I have few classes in First that I want to use in Second. Earlier, I just used to copy the files and modify it in second, but now since I am using SVN, I think it makes sense having just one copy of the class files and reusing them.

How can i check out the classes in First to be used in Second? And when I modify the classes, how can i update First??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a sub folder (or the entire repository) of repo `First` in repo `Second` using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

This way when `Second` is checked out, it will also check out the files referenced from repo `First`.

Then, when you are using repo `Second`, and you modify the referenced class from `First`, you can commit them back. You will have to do this explicitly at the folder level used in the `svn:externals` reference, though. If you commit at the top-level of `Second`, it will not automatically commit changes to the sub-folder referencing `First`.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but I am not able to use it in Tortoise SVN. Sorry, but I am new to SVN :). So, should i add svn:externals to the folder in repo 1 or the file I want to reference?    Just to be clear, I don't want all the files in repo 1, but just one file inside a folder. eg: /repo1/class/db.php and not all fiels in /repo1/class/

Comment: You would create and commit a sub-folder in `Second` where you want the `First` code to appear. Then, in TortoiseSVN, right-click the folder you just created/committed and select *Tortoise/SVN/Properties*. Click *New*, select *svn:externals* in the dropdown, and use the repo URL of `First` as the *Property value*. Commit this change. Then, when you update, it will pull in the code from `First` into this directory.

Comment: When I try this for svn:externals, ^/../First/class/db.php db.php, I get the error "Repository UUID 'e2532d42-4d9d-f244-9935-22916a410asd' doesn't match expected". If I give ^/../First/class db.php, all files in class folder are getting created in a folder db.php in the second. All I want is only db.php...

Comment: You can't do it at the file level, it must be at the directory level. If you only want one file, then put it in its own folder...

Comment: Is there a solution to my problem. My class folder in First contains many classes which I don't want to use in Second. I guess this is a common problem people face when handling multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Either add projects that exist in First in Second, or add the files from First into your project/solution in Second.  Note that this will assume a directory structure.  For example: if First needs class A from Second, in the first solution, provide a link to file "..\First\A.class".  Then it will be compiled into your Second project, but will really reference the file in the other repository, so updates to it will be made in the first repository.